# SWT Overriding Cancel Button

Tags: java, swt

My dialog is extending TitleAreaDialog.  On the dialog, I have a Close Dialog Button. It is just basically calling the method close(); when the button is clicked.

The problem I am having is when the user clicks the Window Close (Red X), it is calling something other than the close method.  I think it might be calling a Cancel Method.

Checking the returnCode, I see that when close is pressed, it returns 0.  But when the X is pressed, it returns 1.

How can I override the X press, to just call the close method, like the button press?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you:

[Handling Window Close Events in JFace](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2005/10/25/handling-window-close-events-in-jface.html)

Basically add this to your dialog:

```
protected void handleShellCloseEvent() {
    // Do whatever you want
    // for example: setReturnCode(OK);
}
```